# Wife is a Chinese Citizen I am a US Citizen, should we go through Chinese passport control together or separately?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, china, chinese-citizens

I recently got married and my wife and I are flying back to China for a wedding reception. When we enter china should we go through passport control together as we are a family unit or separately because of our different citizenship status. And if we go through passport control together do we enter in the Chinese National line or  the Foreigner line?

I was not sure whether the policy in China is the same as entering the US, where we should enter together and should use the US citizen line, and it's hard to find information on this.

Comment: In every country I know of it's OK for immediate families to go together.

Comment: While I can't answer your question there's something you should be aware of:  You are presumably going to be staying with her family.  This means you need to register with the local police station.  For us this has always been easy but I've heard of it being a hassle in some areas.  Officially you need the official occupant of the property there but we have always been able to do it ourselves.

Comment: Also, if you travel around China beware that not all hotels will allow you to stay.  If you do the bookings in English this won't be an issue, any such hotel can take foreigners.  However, if they do the bookings in Chinese and don't remember to check you can get there and find you have to go find another place to stay.  No fun hauling bags around trying to find a hotel!

Comment: From my experiences, Chinese do not honor lines. Choose whatever line is shortest and go together.